# No graphviz output in console of Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, graphviz

Working on a salary dataset. Everything works fine except when I use the `python-graphviz` module in Spyder 3.3.2 to show the decision tree graph it simply shows an image icon in console window. Well the same thing works on other systems. What I'm missing here?
The output image is here.[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQR0r.png)

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
dtf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtf.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
export_graphviz(dtf, out_file="tree.dot", class_names=["Less than 50k",
                                                   "More than 50k"])

import graphviz
with open("tree.dot") as f:
    dot_graph = f.read()
graphviz.Source(dot_graph)
```

Comment: Is this working for you in the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yep, works in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Ok, I'll add my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*spyder maintainer here*) This seems a limitation of [QtConsole](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole), which is the package that powers our IPython consoles.

Please open an issue on the repo referenced above about this so we don't forget to fix it in the future.